# uglify - read source filepaths from a file?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, uglifyjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I am using uglify in Grunt to minify and concatenate my javascript files. I have stored the filepaths of those js files in a file called "loadlist". I was wondering if there is any way I can make pass "loadlist" to uglify so that it can read and process them.

```
grunt.initConfig({
 uglify: {
   my_target: {
     files: {
        'dest/output.min.js': ['src/input1.js', 'src/input2.js']
     }
   }
 }
});

The sample "loadlist" will file looks like this:-
src/input1.js 
src/input2.js
```

NOTE 1 : The above is just for the sake of an example. The actual loadlist is actually pretty large

Thank you

Comment: You can use `fs` to read the `loadlist` file line by line and pass each into uglify: http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: Not to deviate from the topic, I find ``gulp`` better in such situations, ``code over configurations``.